# How can I achieve a Unix Tail operation without using files. In Ruby

Tags: ruby, tail

I used Ruby to read an image file and save that into a string.

```
partial_image100 = File.read("image.tga")
partial_image99 = File.read("image.tga")
partial_image98 = File.read("image.tga")
...
```

I read those images at one end of a distributed system. In another system I want to do a Tail operation. The system receives just the images.

I have around a 100 partial images. I want to do a Tail operation, like this:

```
tail -c +19 image100 >> image99
tail -c +19 image99 >> image98
tail -c +19 image97 >> image96
...
```

Basically it just removes the first 18 bytes of the partial image and append what is left to the next image.

The problem is that this is slow. Calling 100 unix commands from Ruby is slow. I want to refactor this so that this happen in Ruby world. Just in memory. No files.

How can I do this in Ruby?

Thanks

edit:

The images are stored in a hash like this:

```
{"27"=>"\u0000\u0000\u0002\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u000E\u0001\xD0\a\xD0\a\u0018 \xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF\u0000\xFF\xFF...
```

EDIT:

You have all the relevant code here:  https://gist.github.com/989563

There are two files. The code and a hash object encoded in json in a file. When you run the code there will be two image files created at /tmp

- /tmp/image-tail-merger.tga – The output from the tail-merge algorithm
- /tmp/image-/time/.tga  – the output from the in-memory-tail algorithm

Currently the in-memory algorithm fails because the generated image is a Picasso.

If you manage to make the in-memory-algorithm generate the same image that the tail-merge algorithm do then you have succeeded.

EDIT:

I got it right finally!!!

Here is the code
https://gist.github.com/989563

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try something like this

```
image100 = "some image string"
image99 = "some other image string"

image99 += image100.slice(0,19)
```

EDIT: In your specific example you could do this to iterate through the entire image

```
(image_hash.size..1).each do i
  # Here we use slice to select everything *except* the first 19 bytes
  # Note: To select just the first 19 bytes we could do slice(0,19)
  #       To select just the last 19 bytes we could do slice(-19,19)

  # We then append this result to the next image down the line
  image_hash[i-1] += image_hash[i].slice(19,image_hash[i].size-19)
end
```

If you want to remove the "tailed" bits permanently you can use `slice!` to do an inline replace.

Maybe a bit cleaner:

```
# Strip the headers
image_hash.each { |k,v| v.slice!(0,19) }

# Append them together
(image_hash.keys.sort).collect{ |i| image_hash[i] }.join
```

EDIT: Working code example  https://gist.github.com/989563

Comment: @diedthreetimes: Check the edit. I clarify what the specific format of the string is.

Comment: what is the key to the hash. The partial image?

Comment: @diedthreetimes: The images needs to be tailed in an specific order. Reverse order actually. The key that order and the value is the image.

Comment: @Nerian The order doesn't matter slice(-i,i) acts like a tail on string :) I've updated for your specific example.

Comment: @diedthreetimes: Mmmm I think we are missing something. I got a corrupted image so that means the merger is not working. I will upload a working sample

Comment: @Nerian: I was wrong before this should be working fine. My mistake was tailing the LAST 19 bytes and not the first.

Comment: @diedthreetimes: A tricky problem we have here :) So what should I do?  The idea is remove just the first 19 bytes of the image, as they are the magic number for TGa files. Then append the rest of the image to the other images in succession.

Comment: @Nerian: O man i'm still way off. This can still be done pretty easily one last edit

Answer (score 2):

I might look at [File::Tail](https://github.com/flori/file-tail), similar to the Perl module.

```
File.open(filename) do |log|
 log.extend(File::Tail)
 log.interval = 10
 log.backward(10)
 log.tail { |line| puts line }
end
```

You can also monkey-patch your own `File` to use `File::Tail` as well for cleaner usage.

Comment: But does this writes to disk? The core issue is performance. Is this writing a new file or is this operation done in memory?

Comment: Also, I do not have the file where I do the tail operation. It is a distributed system. All I have is a string with the image.

Comment: Sorry, @Nerian, I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Don't worry, It IS a difficult problem. It is hard to explain too. I added working code that you can use to check a solution. Check the edit. I would appreciate any help ^^

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at [String#unpack](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001112) (and its inverse [Array#pack](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000206)).

In your case some like that should do what you want:

```
trunked = image.unpack('@19c*').pack('c*')
```

Comment: With the string format you provided in your edit, you may want to use `u` string directive instead of `c`.

Comment: I don't quite understand pack and unpack. Correct me if I am wrong: unpack generates an array from a string which has binary data encoded in a format – you specify the format in the argument. Is that right?

Comment: @Nerian, perfectly right. The @ directive allows you to set an offset. In anycase it is the only safe way to go when dealing with binary data. You tell how to handle decoding, signature etc.

Comment: Please check the edit. I added working code that you can run to test a solution. Right now the generated image is a Picasso :) I would appreciate any help.